# Click image within Button control event not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have the following code and the Click event is not firing when I click the image.
When I click outside the image the button click event fires.

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Button x:Name="btnMain" Background="Purple" >             
        <StackPanel x:Name="spButtonPanel" Background="Black">
            <telerik:RadImageEditor x:Name="imgButtonImage" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbButtonText" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

CS:

```
this.btnMain.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnMain_Click);
this.imgButtonImage.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(imgButtonImage_Click);
this.spButtonPanel.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(spButtonPanel_Click);
```

In the x_Click events are simply MessageBox.Show("Button clicked");
Where x is btn_Main etc...

The imgButtonImage_Click will not fire when I click the image.
I have tried also changing ZIndex to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `<telerik:RadImageEditor x:Name="imgButtonImage" />` inside the stackpanel which is inside a button? Having an image editor inside a button doesn't make sense to me.
If you want to show an image with text inside a button you can use something similar to:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}">  
    <StackPanel>  
        <Image Source="{Binding ...}  Margin="10" />  
        <TextBlock Text="Localizable Text" />  
    </StackPanel>  
</Button>
```

To use a base64string as the image source you could do the following:

```
string bgImage64 = //   image stored in string
byte[] binaryData = Convert.FromBase64String(bgImage64);

BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(binaryData);
bi.EndInit();

imgButtonImage.Source = bi;
```

To encapsulate this code, and use directly in the xaml, you can create an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) and use something like `<Image Source="{Binding ...stringDataSource..., Converter={StaticResource MyBase64ImageConverter}}"/>`

Comment: The purpose of the Stackpanel is that the orientation of the collection of controls(I.E. Image and Text) can be changed from horizontal to vertical. The RadImageEditor was taken from some other code - which already has methods to convert the image(which comes as Base64  string) to display in the control.

Comment: I improved my response. I got the idea from the Stackpanel (I use it all the time in buttons) but I'm reluctant to believe the RawImageEditor has the same behavior as an Image inside a button. They have different purposes.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the effort - but BitmapImage does not contain the BeginInit() method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage(v=vs.95).aspx    Any other suggestions?

Comment: Ah, my bad, didn't realized the Silverlight tag! Was looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx Can't confirm rigth now if it's usable in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out with JSimoes help.

```
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.SetSource(new MemoryStream(imageBytes));
        imgButtonImage.Source = bi;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Telerik RadImageEditor control but I guess it handles the mouse bubbling events. You should use tunneling events instead (events names starting with `Preview`) like `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the event to the xaml

```
<Button x:Name="btnMain" Background="Purple" Click="btnMain_Click" >
```